# How can I draw transparent graphics onto transparent BitmapData?

Tags: actionscript-3, rendering, bitmapdata, argb

I'm trying to draw PNGs onto BitmapData that is transparent.

I create my BitmapData like this (using ARGB for the color):

```
new BitmapData(width, height, true, 0x00000000);
```

And clean it by using the same ARGB value:

```
bitmapData.fillRect(bitmapData.rect, 0x00000000);
```

When I use `copyPixels()` to draw graphics onto the cleaned BitmapData, I get this result:

[image]

If I don't use ARGB for the BitmapData color, it works fine:

[image]

But I have to specify a solid fillColor, meaning I can't render what's behind the Bitmap.

How can I make my BitmapData transparent, but not have the above occur?

Comment: Have you tried with mergeAlpha on? I.e.
`copyPixels(myPNG, rect, point, null, null, true);`

Comment: Well, that was surprisingly straightforward for an Adobe product... Added a bit more as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation on `BitmapData::CopyPixels()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29):

"The mergeAlpha property controls whether or not the alpha channel is used *when a transparent image is copied onto another transparent image*. To copy pixels with the alpha channel data, set the mergeAlpha property to true. By default, the mergeAlpha property is false."

For once the Adobe documentation actually speaks the truth.

```
copyPixels(myPNG, rect, point, null, null, true);
```

... should fix it (and did). Guessing it's turned off by default for performance reasons, because I can't really think of a place where it'd be useful to have it off.